# SQL Like query excluding space characeters

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below is a basic idea of how my table looks.

```
id -  Name
1  -  C A D Systems
2  -  A & B Company
3  -  A M A T Systems
4  -  HHH Systems
5  -  A A Systems
```

I am looking for a query to handle this functionality:

- If I search "CAD", I should be able to get C A D Systems back.
- If I search "A&B", I should be able to get A & B Company.
- If I search "H H H Systems", I should be able to get HHH Systems.

Is there a way to search and ignore space characters?

Comment: Replaced `psql` tag with `postgresql`. `psql` is the command line client. The DBMS is named PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `replace()` to remove spaces and then do the comparison:

```
where replace(name, ' ', '') like '%CAD%'
```